# nodejs connect mysql error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I use mysql and express to write a easy login system.

database.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('../config/config');

var pool = mysql.createPool(config.mysql_dev);

var query=function(sql,callback){  
    pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){  
        if(err) console.log("POOL ==> " + err);
        else{  
            conn.query(sql,function(qerr,vals,fields){  
                //release connection  
                conn.release();
                callback(qerr,vals,fields);  

            });  
        }  
    });  
};  

module.exports=query;
```

index.js:

```
router.post('/login',function(req,res){ 
    var query = require('../modules/database');
    query("select * from managers where ManagerID =10001",function(err,vals,fields){  
        var temp=JSON.stringify(vals);

        var manager = JSON.parse(temp)[0];

        if(req.body.password===manager.password){
           req.session.manager = manager;
           res.redirect('/home');
        }
        res.send('ID or password wrong!');
    });
});
```

However, everytime when i get this error:

```
/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at /opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/routes/index.js:40:7
    at Query._callback (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/modules/database.js:16:17)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:144:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:128:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/opt/workspace/project/nodejs-demo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
```

How to solve it? 
I do not know how to solve it and search for a long time.
If i describe it not clearly, just comment and i will add anything i know.

Comment: I think your problem is not with `mysql` but it's that you are trying to change response object after sending it to user. (see stack trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained your problem in comments in code.

```
router.post('/login',function(req,res){ 
    var query = require('../modules/database');
    query("select * from managers where ManagerID =10001",function(err,vals,fields){  
        var temp=JSON.stringify(vals);

        var manager = JSON.parse(temp)[0];

        if(req.body.password===manager.password){
           req.session.manager = manager;


           //You are redirecting user to home
           res.redirect('/home');

           //You should add 'return'
           return;
        }

        //This will only accessible if password is not match
        res.send('ID or password wrong!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I should return in the if:

```
if(req.body.password===manager.password)       
 {
    req.session.manager = manager;
    res.redirect('/home');
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issues in the following snippet.

```
if(req.body.password===manager.password){
   req.session.manager = manager;
   res.redirect('/home');
}
res.send('ID or password wrong!');
```

It is clear from error stack trace that you are trying to set headers after it is being sent. It means that `if` statement executes first and if it true, it redirect to `/home`, after that it exits the `if` clause and tries to send message to user.

**Possible Solution**

```
if(req.body.password===manager.password){
   req.session.manager = manager;
   res.redirect('/home');
} else {
   res.send('ID or password wrong!');
}
```

Check it, if it helps you.